# What is the status of the Infinity Stones post Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, plot-device, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, the heroes travel back in time to "borrow" the Infinity Stones from the past to use them in the future.

I get that. At the end of the movie,

> Captain America travels back to return the Infinity Stones to their various points in time to merge the two timelines (I think).

---

> But because the movie has gone for an alt-timeline mutliverse version of time travel, it's not a problem. It just means that there's now an alternative timeline kicking off in 2014 in which Nebula and Thanos don't exist. That timeline doesn't have a snap. But that doesn't mean that the MCU timeline - the one we've been watching for the last 11 years - is changed at all. Because changing the past doesn't alter the future, remember - killing baby Thanos wouldn't change a thing in the current timeline, as they point out, and that also means that killing Thanos 2014 equally has not affect on the current continuity.
>
> [DenofGeek](https://www.denofgeek.com/uk/movies/avengers-endgame/64877/avengers-endgame-very-spoilery-questions-and-theories)

**But**, if the timelines are reset and the snap still happened and the early events of *Avengers: Endgame* (before the "5 years later") then aren't the Stones now destroyed in the *ongoing* timeline?

Specifically, what happened to the Time Stone? Surely Doctor Strange would be concerned about losing it.

(or is the last point opinion based?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**NOTE: this answer is totally wrong! The Russo brothers have confirmed that [alternate realities are created without removing Infinity Stones from the timeline](https://ew.com/movies/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-russo-brothers-captain-america/).**

> It just means that there's now an alternative timeline kicking off in 2014 in which Nebula and Thanos don't exist.

Just like in the movie itself, people love to confidently state how time travel works, despite the fact that it's an entirely fictional concept, and thus works exactly how the authors of any story decide it works, regardless of your own conception of temporal logic.

The movie goes to considerable effort to explain its time travel rules, including the alternative timeline question. The Ancient One even draws us a picture. Here's what she tells us:

- The Infinity Stones (as a whole) are responsible for creating the flow of time in the universe.
- If you remove an Infinity Stone from the timeline via time travel, an alternative reality will be created, without that stone in it. This would be *bad* for that reality.
- By implication, aside from that, time travel does *not* create ongoing alternate realities, yet does not affect the past, or the present.

So, after Cap returns the Infinity Stones to their original places in the timeline, everything is fine, and still happens in the way we saw it happen. Thus the Infinity Stones are eventually used to destroy themselves in Thanos' garden. (For some reason, this is presumably fine for the universe, even though the stones are apparently responsible for creating its flow of time.)

I'm not saying it makes sense! I'm just saying this is how the movie tells us it works.

Comment: Yep this is the way I understood it too, +1 because I think you explained it clearer than me

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: aw cheers man. This is why I'm not keen on time travel stuff — it makes everyone's brain itch, because there's almost no way it can really make sense to our puny mortal minds. But I think the movie does *fairly* clearly rule out alternative timelines — although, having mentioned them, I wouldn't be surprised if they used the concept within a few years, either in the movies or on Disney Plus.

Comment: Sorry Paul, but I disagree. It's true that the Ancient One shows us that timelines with Infinity Stones removed are unstable, but she explicitly shows us a new "branch" being formed by time travel. Putting the stones back doesn't mean that branch disappears - it simply means that the branch doesn't turn black and decay, at least that's my reading. Yes, Cap puts the stones back at the end - but that doesn't mean that Loki didn't escape with the Space Stone in 2012 in another timeline, or that Thanos didn't disappear in 2014 in another.

Comment: It's also worth noting that with my reading, there are now 3 timelines in the MCU - there are also 3 TV shows planned, two of which star characters that are no longer alive in the main timeline but would (or at least, could) still be alive in the other timelines created. I suspect this was deliberate set up for whatever Phase 4 ends up being, not merely coincidence.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: your apologies will crumble to dust before the awesome power of the Infinity Time Travel Rules! “she explicitly shows us a new "branch" being formed by time travel” — I think she explicitly shows us a new branch being formed by removing an Infinity Stone from the timeline. I may be wrong — I saw Endgame twice in 18 hours, so sleep deprivation is probably a factor — but I think putting the stone back literally gets rid of the alternate reality in the Ancient One's diagram.

Comment: @DrRDizzle: “with my reading, there are now 3 timelines in the MCU - there are also 3 TV shows planned” — sure, but I think what the Ancient One and the Hulk actually say contradicts the possibility that alternate realities exist. Of course, they can do what they want, and the power to dodge continuity must be incredibly tempting. I wouldn't be surprised if they did decide alternate realities are a thing, but *Endgame* itself very explicitly tells us that they aren't.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Putting the stone back the moment it disappears would prevent a new branch being formed, yes - but only if that's the only change to the timeline made, and as we see, there are other changes made when the Avengers travel back in time, such as Loki escaping in 2012 or Thanos and his armies disappearing in 2014. I don't see how putting the stone back prevents branches caused by those changes. I could be wrong, of course, but like I said, I suspect this is deliberate set up for the future. Or, to put it another way - why else show us Loki disappearing?

Comment: @DrRDizzle: “Putting the stone back the moment it disappears would prevent a new branch being formed, yes - but only if that's the only change to the timeline made” — says who? Literally no-one says that in the movie, and it doesn't track with what we see in the movie, as the Avengers made a bunch of other changes just by being there. Does each change create an alternate reality? If not, why not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92892/discussion-between-paul-d-waite-and-dr-r-dizzle).

Comment: To be honest I read that interview and I get the feeling that the Russos don't necessarily understand the time travel concept they set up. They say it'd be an alternate reality but then answer the how as if they don't know. I remain unmoved on the original theory and think the way you originally wrote this is correct still.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: I guess they probably want to leave wiggle room for the people running the Disney+ shows and writing future movies. No point in setting hard rules about the mechanics until you have a storytelling need for them. I'd love to see an actual transcript of the interview, rather than the terrible content ew.com craps out.

Comment: You might want to update again to note that the writers agree with this interpretation as well as saying the Russos don't.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot ah, yeah I guess. Most movies don’t have this much paperwork!

Answer (score 4):

The status of the Infinity Stones in my mind is quite simple, the ones from the past are back in the past returned as they were taken so that the timeline doesn't spawn alternate timelines as explained by The Ancient One. The ones in the future are still destroyed as Thanos had destroyed them, assuming he wasn't lying of course, which I don't think he was considering past Thanos' comments about it.

> It just means that there's now an alternative timeline kicking off in 2014 in which Nebula and Thanos don't exist.

FWIW I think this statement in the article is wrong, there is no alternative timeline starting in 2014 because the Infinity Stones were placed back where they came from.

As for whether Doctor Strange would be concerned about losing the Time Stone, probably not really. He is concerned about keeping the universe alive and losing the Time Stone is a small price to pay for that.

Comment: Dormammu might disagree with this :)

Comment: "there is no alternative timeline starting in 2014 because the Infinity Stones were placed back where they came from"  -> What about the fact that Loki escaped with the Tesseract? Did Captain America fix that too?

Comment: @Paulie_D Well there is going to be a second Doctor Strange movie I think...

Comment: @Fatalize We don't know and we don't know if he ever left the timeline with the Space Stone or not, if he didn't then nothing matters. Of course Loki is getting a TV series so we'll see.

Comment: @Fatalize: for all we know, Loki used the Tesseract to assault Asgard, failed, and ended up in jail on Asgard ready for Thor 2.

Comment: Certainly we know Loki has a TV show to make...he'll be busy!

Comment: "there is no alternative timeline starting in 2014 because the Infinity Stones were placed back where they came from" - can you clarify what the timeline looks like then? In 2014 thanos time travels to the future and is killed there. Where does the thanos in 2015 come from at this point? My expectation watching the end of the film was that the snap was going to send them all back to the past with no memories of the future or the information they found out about it so the timeline could continue but that doesn't seem to have happened (though perhaps it did and the turning to ash was theirreturn

Comment: @Chris The Thanos that travels to the future is a Thanos in an alternative timeline by putting the stones back the original Thanos in 2014 isn't affected.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: Ah, ok. I *think* that makes sense. It is giving me a headache though. :)

Comment: Actually, there are potentially now two alternate timelines out there. The first is where Loki regained the Tesseract and escaped Earth before Thor could return him to Asgard. Interestingly, this timeline also includes a brainwashed Captain America that Hydra now believes is one of them. The second is where Cap stayed behind to live out his life with Peggy.

Comment: @aleppke the Loki one is a potential, assuming he takes the Stone out of the timeline which we have no indication of. The Cap with Peggy one is apparently the main timeline and not an alternate one.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Cap couldn't have lived in the current timeline. The movie clearly establishes that time travel cannot change the past of the original timeline. The Winter Soldier also clearly establishes that Peggy eventually moved on and married someone else. Therefore, Cap could not lived a life with her in the original timeline.

Comment: @aleppke I haven’t seen TWS but who’s to say that someone else isn’t Cap? He is married as the old man.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Peggy says Captain America saved the life of the man who would become her husband. Although, they never name her husband so I suppose it is technically possible it was Cap all along and their relationship was a secret the entire time so as not to disrupt the timeline. And then when Cap goes to see her in TWS, she pretends that's the first time she's seen him since the plane went down so as not to tip him off. But I honestly doubt it. She appears genuinely upset that he's alive and she didn't wait for him.

Comment: @aleppke, the timeline where Cap stayed behind must be the main timeline, because the elderly future Cap was in the main timeline.

Comment: @HarryJohnston In a movie where they spend half of it jumping through timelines, that literally means nothing. They clearly established that changing the past cannot alter the present and a Captain America living a full life would definitely change the present. No, the only thing that makes sense is that he and Peggy lived in an alternate timeline and then he returned to the main timeline after she died.

Comment: @aleppke, all the alternate timelines [were supposed to be eliminated](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/211031/5930) when the infinity stones were replaced.  And if Cap was in an alternate timeline I don't see any sensible way that he could have gotten back to the main one.  But I concede your interpretation isn't implausible.  I personally don't like it, not least because of the ethical questions it raises, but YMMV.

Comment: @aleppke, incidentally, I'm sure Cap saved his own life more than once, so what Peggy said might still have been true, from a certain point of view. :-)

Comment: @aleppke, when a young Steve visited Peggy in TWS, she was well into Alzheimer's-induced dementia. Note that the end of the scene she's forgotten he's been sitting there talking to her the entire time and acts as if he just arrived.

Comment: @KeithMorrison Indeed. And you'll also notice that when she does this, she laments that he was "gone so long". If she had lived a full life with him, I would expect that she'd be surprised at how young he is again rather than the fact that he's there at all.

Comment: @aleppke Have you ever met anyone with dementia? Unfortunately I have and it is very sad what can happen to the mind.

Answer (score 3):

The Russo’s have confirmed the infinity stones are not destroyed at all. Thanos just reduces them to atoms but they still exist in the MCU

https://www.google.com/amp/s/screenrant.com/avengers-endgame-director-russos-infinity-stones-still-exist/amp/